# mongodb mongoose unit of maxDistance

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongoose

In my application, I am trying to use, 
RentModel.find({prop_location : { $near : [msg.lat, msg.lng], 
$maxDistance : 500}}, function(err, docs){} 
I have only one value in the database with latitude, longitude of san 
francisco. 
Now,

1. 1. When there is no maxDistance => It finds out the location
      perfectly  from anywhere.
   2. When I add maxDistance as 5 and search exactly at the same
      location  (with same latitude, longitude), it does not find the
      location.
   3. If it is 50, same as point 2.
   4. If it is 500, I can even find the location from London.

What's wrong ?

what is the unit of distance ? 
I want to find out everything within 5km (kilometer) distance. 
will db.executeCommand solve my problem ? need to check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your model schema for the geo tagging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to my problem.
Theoretically longitude is x-axis and latitude is y-axis. But we are used to latitude- longitude rather than longitude-latitude...
So the way I was searching was wrong

```
$near : [msg.lat, msg.lng]
```

When I changed this to **$near : [msg.lng, msg.lat]** , it started working even with 5KM... So ordering was the problem.

Comment: This will give you the distance assuming the earth is flat thou.

Answer (score 7):

You need to divide the maxdistance value by 111.12 (one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers) to convert the degree radius to km distance.

so you can try this

```
 RentModel.find({prop_location : { $near : [msg.lat, msg.lng], $maxDistance : 500/111.2}})
```

But the same works different is sphere queries, there you have to divide the degree radius  by earth-radius 6371 to work with km values

Comment: that's a good piece of information. Thanks. So for 5km, I have to divide 5 by 111.12, 5/111.12. If I do not divide 5 by 111.12, this would indicate that I am searching for something in range 555.6km (5 x 111.12), why does not it work, any idea ? I am using '2d' index.

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? do you have a relevant data for the distance 555 kms.?

Comment: ofcourse I have relevant data within 1km range.. but as I mentioned it can not find if maxDistance is 5 or 50. But it can find if it is 500. Also I tried dividing it by 111.12 and this time find did not fetch any result. Is it working for you ?

Comment: The order of specifying lat and long are wrong in your answer. It should be [msg.lng, msg.lat]