# Mongoose max distance doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have two coordinates:

```
55.703457,
12.58928

55.7001719,
12.5479853
```

Now, these two points are approximately 2 km from each other.

now i try to make one search:

```
    mongoose.models.apartments.find({
    loc: {
        $near: [55.7001719,
            12.5479853],
        $maxDistance: 1
    }
}
```

(Which as you can see is the second point) and I set the `$maxDistance to 1` however the query still returns both results.

My question is why?

**Update**

When i change the `$maxDistance` to:

```
$maxDistance : 0.03
```

it correctly only find one result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605813/mongodb-mongoose-unit-of-maxdistance

Comment: @Aky_0788 i have already looked at the answers for this question however that did not solve my issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947157/mongoose-near-query-on-2dsphere-indexed-field-not-returning-valid-results

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib refer this module for getting distance